# How to v-bind method without execute "automatically"?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I try to use the package "vue2-touch-events".
I have now a list of many images and want to display them in a popup, if I press and hold the image and open the image with an normal click.

The logic behind the clicks is no problem.

Right now I call the methods like this:

```
<v-card ... v-touch:start="startHandler" v-touch:end="endHandler">
     <v-img ... >
     </v-img>
</v-card>
```

This works like it should. But I need the image id inside the Handler. When I pass it like "endHandler(imageId)", it always executes the method on every page load for every image in that list...

How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write the handler like this "endHandler(imageId)" you are executing the handler, instead passing the function's pointer/reference.

In order to avoid that behaviour, you may need to wrap the handler call with a inline (anonymous) function like this:

```
<v-card ... v-touch:start="startHandler" v-touch:end="function() { endHandler(imageId); }">
     <v-img ... >
     </v-img>
</v-card>
```

Comment: it does seem like Vue has support for what OP is trying [1], but it may only be for events (via the "v-on:" syntax)
[1]: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers

Comment: I definitely don't work with the subject very often. It works perfectly. But I will take a closer look later to understand "why".

Comment: @AndrewAult yes, I know about v-on and v-bind, but I don't know, how to use v-on with v-touch from the "vue2-touch-events" package. If that would work, it would be the (I think so) more beautiful way, but Luis answer works too.